# Net-EMF in a branch?

Tags: voltage, electromagnetism, kirchhoffs-laws

Given this initial circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzulv9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

After some time(\$ \Delta t\$) there are multiple induced EMF's within the third branch leading to the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnTAih.png)</sup>

At the third branch, will the net-voltage Always be: Applied + EMF2 - EMF1?

Comment: What do you mean by "at the third branch".  The voltage across R2 (which is PS-EMF1+EMF2) or the voltage across the entire vertical section of the schematic (which is PS)?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from the vague description, but it seems you want to know the voltage across R2 as a function of the three voltage sources.  That is

V<sub>R2</sub> = -PS + EMF1 - EMF2

across R2 top to bottom, and for the polarities of the voltage sources as you show them in your bottom drawing:

[image]